# Which practices should i use while generating SMS codes for auth on my project?

Tags: sms, code-signing

Let's imagine that we have an SMS verification auth, and using random 4-digit codes,
i.e. 1234, 5925, 1342 and etc.

I'm using this random inclusive algorithm on my node.js server:

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min); //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
}

const another_one_code = getRandomIntInclusive(1000, 9999);
```

taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Seems i have range from 1000 to 9999 and have some questions about security:

1. I'm using good algo? Maybe i need to use something better?
2. Will it increase security if i will check previous sent code for {$n} last minutes from db and regenerate another one if it will be same (brute same code twice case), so user always gets random 5941-2862-1873-3855-2987 without 1023-1023-2525-2525-3733-3733 case? I understand that chance is low, but anyway...

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using good algo? Maybe i need to use something better?

Which generator is being used by `Math.random()`?

Have a look at the footnote on that Mozilla page:

> Math.random() *does not* provide cryptographically secure random numbers. Do not use them for anything related to security

> Will it increase security if i will check previous sent code for {$n} last minutes from db and regenerate another one if it will be same (brute same code twice case), so user always gets random 5941-2862-1873-3855-2987 without 1023-1023-2525-2525-3733-3733 case? I understand that chance is low, but anyway...

No. You shouldn't try to make numbers "more random" by avoiding repetitions. It's the property of random numbers that there is a chance that the next one will be the same as the previous, and it's ok. You would actually *weak* it by discarding those $n last codes.

I would actually try to implement HOTP / TOTP on the sms codes. You don't really need to, a random number would do, but that way you could easily change the users from sms authentication to local-app authentication, with no changes on the verifier code.